# why can't I insert this processing instruction into an svg via ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm setting an xml-stylesheet reference to the top of of an svg dynamically through js. The svg has been imported into the page via an object tag in the html.  Here's the function:

```
function setSvgXmlStylesheet() {
    var cssPath = $('#hdnServerRoot').val() + 'css/app.min.css'; 
    var nodeValue = 'href="' + cssPath + '" type="text/css"';
    var document = d3.select(globals.MapContainer[0][0])[0][0];
    var pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', nodeValue);
    var x = document.insertBefore(pi, document.firstChild);
}
```

This works in Chrome but not ie.  What do I need to do differently to ensure that this works in ie?

**UPDATE**

Looks like this could potentially be an issue with XmlSerializer differences for IE.  Here are the first few lines of my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

The  comment above is returned as document.childNodes[0] in IE and the js I provided successfully inserts a new xml-stylesheet node above this node based on object inspection. However, the alert produced by the following line of code only shows the svg markup from the  line down:

alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document));

Do I need to create a special configuration for the native Xmlserializer in IE or use a 3rd party js lib or some type of polyfill?

Comment: Hi, yes.... IE does not like the unclosed svg tags that svg editors like adobe and inkscape use.... To debug these issues, you need to set up IE's developer messages... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"...save changes.... load your d3 project, then press f12>Console tab, svg self closing tag errors are listed. Inkscape has options to save svg files without the proprietary markup, that some editors add. In the Visual Studio IDE, nonself closing svg element errors are also highlighted by intellisence.

Comment: thanks rob.  I removed the 2nd and 3rd lines of xml from the example I provided above.  The svg initially loads as expected without issues. But my js which inserts the css reference still doesn't work successfully on ie although it still works successfully on chrome

Comment: What does the dev console say? any more errors? If it works in other browsers but not IE, it will be because of Addons or blocked content because of user settings for security, ActiveX filtering or Tracking Protection.... The d3 documentation recommends using inline style blocks... you could test by replacing your external stylesheet call with an inline style block... Then using the DOM Explorer, confirm that all style rules are applied as expected.... you will need to provide a reproduction link for more help.